# How to create an image map from a jpeg that then displays modal images with text

Tags: html, css, modal-dialog, maps, dreamweaver

I have a jpeg image that needs to have multiple hotspots that will open modal images.  The modal images are needed because we want an image to appear and have descriptive text describing the specific service.  We are using Bootstrap so the image map needs to be responsive, I have tried it many different ways directly in notepad++ with no success.  I am currently trying it in Dreamweaver. I found this code on Adobe's community forum, it works with my images on a test page but when applied to my actual website page it does not.

```
<div class="product">
<a href="#" class="hotspot spot_1" data-modal=".modal_1">+</a>
<a href="#" class="hotspot spot_2" data-modal=".modal_2">+</a>
<a href="#" class="hotspot spot_3" data-modal=".modal_3">+</a>
<a href="#" class="hotspot spot_4" data-modal=".modal_4">+</a>
<a href="#" class="hotspot spot_5" data-modal=".modal_5">+</a>
<a href="#" class="hotspot spot_6" data-modal=".modal_6">+</a>
<img src="../images/img_map/pse_23.png" alt="project_arc">

<div class="modal modal_1">
<div class="modal_info">
<img src="../website_2020/images/img_map/tanks.jpg" alt="Tiger">
<h3>FEL 1</h3>
<p>Some text goes here. Some text goes here. Some text goes here. Some text goes here.</p>
<a href="#">X</a>
</div>
<!-- end modal info -->
</div>
<!-- end modal_1 -->
<div class="modal modal_2">
<div class="modal_info">
<img src="../images/img_map/loadout.jpg" alt="Tiger">
<h3>FEL 2</h3>
<p>Some text goes here. Some text goes here. Some text goes here. Some text goes here.</p>
<a href="#">X</a>
</div>
<!-- end modal info -->
</div>
<!-- end modal_2 -->
<div class="modal modal_3">
<div class="modal_info">
<img src="../images/img_map/P5140066.jpg" alt="Tiger">
<h3>FEL 3</h3>
<p>Some text goes here. Some text goes here. Some text goes here. Some text goes here.</p>
<a href="#">X</a>
</div>
<!-- end modal info -->
</div>
<!-- end modal_3 -->
<div class="modal modal_4">
<div class="modal_info">
<img src="../images/img_map/PC130001.jpg" alt="Tiger">
<h3>Detailed Engineering</h3>
<p>Some text goes here. Some text goes here. Some text goes here. Some text goes here.</p>
<a href="#">X</a>
</div>
<!-- end modal info -->
</div>
<!-- end modal_4 -->
<div class="modal modal_5">
<div class="modal_info">
<img src="../images/img_map/girt_install.jpg" alt="Tiger">
<h3>Construction & Purchasing</h3>
<p>Some text goes here. Some text goes here. Some text goes here. Some text goes here.</p>
<a href="#">X</a>
</div>
<!-- end modal info -->
</div>
<!-- end modal_5 -->
<div class="modal modal_6">
<div class="modal_info">
<img src="../images/img_map/fire_protect.jpg" alt="Tiger">
<h3>Commissioning</h3>
<p>Some text goes here. Some text goes here. Some text goes here. Some text goes here.</p>
<a href="#">X</a>
</div>
<!-- end modal info -->
</div>
<!-- end modal_6 -->
</div>
<!-- end product -->
<!--javascript used -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="

crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>

$(document).ready(function(){

$('.product a').css('cursor' , 'pointer').click(function(){

$('.modal').fadeOut();

var modal = $(this).attr('data-modal');

if($(modal).is(':visible') == true) {

$(modal).fadeOut();

}

else {

$(modal).fadeIn();

}

});

});

</script>

<!--css used -->
/*project arc styles*/
.product {position: relative;
width: 95%;
margin: 0 auto;}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {

.product {width: 100%;}}

.product img {max-width: 100%;}

.hotspot {position: absolute;
display: inline-block;
background-color: red;
color: #fff;
text-decoration: none;
padding: 10px 15px;
border-radius: 50%;}

.hotspot:hover {background-color: #666;}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
.hotspot {padding: 5px 10px;}}

.spot_1 {top: 60%;
left: 23%;}

.spot_2 {top: 50%;
left: 42%;}

.spot_3 {top: 30%;
left: 55%;}

.spot_4 {top: 20%;
left: 70%;}

.spot_5 {top: 55%;
left: 60%;}

.spot_6 {top: 10%;
left: 80%;}

.modal {position: absolute;
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
background-color: #fff;
display: none;
box-shadow: 2px 2px 9px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
width: 40%;
margin: 0 30%;
color: #000;}

.modal h3 {margin: 0;
padding: 10px 0;}

.modal p {margin: 0;
padding: 0 0 5px 0;}

.modal_info {padding: 15px;}

.modal_info a{position: absolute;
top: -28px;
right: 0;
display: inline-block;
text-decoration: none;
background-color: #000;
color: #fff;
padding: 7px 10px 4px 10px;}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {.modal_1, .modal_2, .modal_3, .modal_4, .modal_5 {
top: 0;
margin: 0 5%;
transform: translateY(0);
width: 90%;}}
```

Comment: Can you post what you have already tried so we can try and aid in what went wrong? Currently this is far too open ended to answer.

Comment: Well I did find something from Adobe's community that works in a test html page by itself, but when I tried to add the html, css and js to my real web page something is missing

Comment: the code is too long to add, darn it!

Comment: I edited the original post, sorry I am new here!